# Is there any complex value for $x$ where $|x| < 0$?

Tags: terminology, absolute-value

What I'm really asking is if I get to a point in a calculation where I have $|x| = -4$, do I say

> There is no solution for $x$

or do I say

> There is no solution for $x ∈ ℝ$

Comment: The first one as the absolute value is strictly non-negative regardless of whether x is real or complex.

Comment: I would use the first one. Anyway, this question makes sense only when you forget to look at the domain of your equation: a bad mistake in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, if it depends on where you are *looking* for the solution. It is true that there is no solution for $x\in\mathbb C$, but if the question starts with "Does there exist such $x\in\mathbb N$[...]", then I would still say "there is no solution in $\mathbb N$".

Answer (score 0):

if $$x=a+ib$$ then we get $$|x|=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)}$$ and this is not negative